# Vue2.0 V-if condition meet then loop div-for

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

im working with one project to retrieve the ballNum if selected :value=betType.option equal to 1 and when i click the dropdown selection list on the first select. it seems nothing to display of the ballNum

HTML :

```
<h1 class="header-title">
                    <select style="border: 0;background: #d91e38;color: #ffffff;" v-model="option" @change="selectbetType(option)">
                        <option v-for="betType in betList.allBet" :value="betType.option">{{betType.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </h1>

<div class="pr bet-num clearfix" v-if="betType.option='1'">
                    <div class="bit fl">万位</div><i class="dot-right"></i>
                    <ul class="num-type display-box text-center fr" v-model="optionUnique" @change="selectoptionUnique(optionUnique)">
                        <li v-for="unique in uniqueBet" :value="unique.optionUnique" :class="{ 'active': unique === selected }" @click="choose(unique)">{{unique.uniqueBetz}}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="num-ball fr ballNum">
                        <li v-for="cell in ballNum" :class="{ 'active': cell === selected }" @click="choose(cell)">{{cell.num}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Data :

```
 betList: {
                allBet : [
                  {
                    option : '1',
                    name : '五星-直选复式',
                    betTypeZ : [
                      {
                        digitPlace: [
                          {optionPlace: '万位'},
                          {optionPlace: '千位'},
                          {optionPlace: '白位'},
                          {optionPlace: '十位'},
                          {optionPlace: '个位'}
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        ballNum: [
                          {num: '0', selected: true},
                          {num: '1', selected: false},
                          {num: '2', selected: false},
                          {num: '3', selected: false},
                          {num: '4', selected: false},
                          {num: '6', selected: false},
                          {num: '7', selected: false},
                          {num: '8', selected: false},
                          {num: '9', selected: false}
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        uniqueBet: [
                          {uniqueBetz: '全', selected: true, optionUnique: ['0']},
                          {uniqueBetz: '大', selected: false, optionUnique: ['1']},
                          {uniqueBetz: '小', selected: false, optionUnique: ['2']},
                          {uniqueBetz: '奇', selected: false, optionUnique: ['3']},
                          {uniqueBetz: '偶', selected: false, optionUnique: ['4']},
                          {uniqueBetz: '清', selected: false, optionUnique: ['5']}
                        ],
                      }
                    ]
                  },
```

Comment: I can see that you have `v-if="betType.option='1'"`, did you mean `v-if="betType.option==='1'"`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Hi ya if option ===1